# Cast expression tree to void

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Given some expression tree `inner`, I want to wrap it inside no-op expression of type `void`. Expression `inner` should still be evaluated, but its return type should be thrown away. How do I do it?

If you are curious as to why I would want to do it, one possible application for such casting is `Expression.Switch`, which requires all `Expression.SwitchCase` expressions to return the same type.

My current workaround is to cast everything to type `Object` by wrapping `inner` like this: `Expression.Block(inner, Expression.Constant(null))`. Such solution seems weird, bulks up my code, and possibly complicates the generated MSIL code too.

Comment: Can you please share some of the code that you're working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [the overload of `Expression.Switch()` that lets you specify the return type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630269). If you specify `void`, then expressions of any type will be accepted as the cases. In this overload, you also need to specify the `defaultBody` and `comparison` parameters, but you can just make them `null`.

Another option is indeed to use `Expression.Block()`, but again [the overload that lets you specify the type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630289). In your case, that would be something like:

```
Expression.Block(typeof(void), inner)
```

I don't expect this to have any significant effect on the generated IL.